# Help getting this integral into specific form for integration.(Polynomial Division)

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, indefinite-integrals

I need to get 
$$\frac{x^4-2x^2+4x+1}{x^3-x^2-x+1}
$$
into a specific form for integration.
I have factored out my denominator to $(x-1)^2(x+1)$ through grouping.
I am unsure how to use polynomial division to divide this because of the factored denominator and I have divided it by the unfactored denominator and arrived with a remainder which didn't help at all with the integration process.

Comment: An exponent was missing, I added $2$, but it could be $3$, please check.

Comment: Thanks, its correct now, much appreciated!

Comment: Divide before factoring the bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The polynomial long division gives
$$
x^4-2x^2+4x+1=(x^3-x^2-x+1)(x+1)+4x
$$
so your fraction is
$$
\frac{x^4-2x^2+4x+1}{x^3-x^2-x+1}=x+1+\frac{4x}{x^3-x^2-x+1}
=x+1+\frac{4x}{(x-1)^2(x+1)}
$$
Now you can find the partial fraction decomposition
$$
\frac{4x}{(x-1)^2(x+1)}=
\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{C}{x+1}
$$